# Trying to acquire the YouTube player ID with fancybox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, fancybox, fancybox-3

I am using fancybox v3.3.5 to display a YouTube video in a lightbox. When the video is done playing I want to use the YouTube API to be able to receive a callback when the video has finished playing. **The YouTube API requires the player ID**. I am new to using iframes but it seems like the element I am after that carries the ID is in a document layered over my document. With this being the case I can't use something like `document.querySelector('')` to grab it.

`console.log($.fancybox.getInstance());` logs a very large object and although I haven't found it yet, I think this specific div with the player ID may live here.

There are a few fiddles that will come up in google searches on how to achieve getting a callback when the video has ended with the YouTube API and fancybox but they use an older deprecated version of fancybox which I am not allowed to use.

Here is an image of the div I am after along with the getInstance() object.

[div that contains the ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emd0k.jpg)
[getInstance() object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQlRM.jpg)

HTML:

```
<a class="fancy" data-fancybox data-width="640" data-height="360" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=6kkW6qK0GCs&amp;autoplay=0">
  <div class="tutorial">See how it works
    <i class="play circle icon play-button"></i>
    <br>
  </div>
</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like this:

`$.fancybox.getInstance().current.$content.find('iframe').attr('id')`

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.5 getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Your comment does not give any clue or idea what are you talking about. Is this related to fancybox?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, I'm trying `$.fancybox.getInstance().current.$content.find('iframe').attr('id')` to get id of iframe currently playing youtube video

Comment: I was able to get id in afterShow event on fancybox `var id = $.fancybox.getInstance().current.$iframe.attr('id');`